# NameNode in hadoop not running and no access to (http://localhost:50030)

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I'm using Hadoop 1.2.1 standalone mode .. when i use jps command the output is :

2528 TaskTracker
3044 Jps
2380 JobTracker
2140 DataNode
2286 SecondaryNameNode

There is no NameNode running i don't know why ?..

And when i try to open the http://localhost:50030 ... its won't open

http://localhost:50070 open .. but can't open   :
Browse the filesystem
Namenode Logs

when i try to be root by using sudo su it give me this :

hduser is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this problem happens after the laptop shutdown while hadoop process still running .. i had to reinstall hadoop and it worked correctly.